# Opening Windows Child Form within a panel in MDI Parent Form

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I have this method(below) that works well First time it's called:

```
public void showForm(Form _form, Form _main)
    {
        if (_main != null)
        {
            foreach (Form otherForms in this.MdiChildren)
            {
                otherForms.Close();
            }
        }

        _form.MdiParent = this;
        _form.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        _form.TopLevel = false;
        _form.TopMost = true;
        _form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

        this.MDIChildPanel.Controls.Add(_form);
        _form.BringToFront();
        _form.Show();
    }
```

on Form_Load event for MDI Parent Form i call the method above as shown below and it works well:

```
private void MDIRental_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        showForm(new Login(), null);
    }
```

I then try to call the method above from another event handler and it just doesnt work as show below: help

```
private void manageUsersToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        showForm(new Users(), null);
    }
```

Comment: You have Single.  Are you getting more than on item?

Comment: I meet some errors when I used your code. Therefore, I  suggest that you can provide a completed code with me.